# How to generate a large PSD matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, where $\mathcal{O}(n) \sim 10^3$

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization, simulation

I would like to generate a large PSD matrix, i.e., $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, where $\mathcal{O}(n) \sim 10^3$. The entries of the matrix should be randomly generated using a standard function in Python, or Mathematica or any other language.

The current method I am using is as follows:

1. First, generate a matrix $P$ with random real and positive values. (I set them to integers by rounding).
2. Set $A = PP^T$

The matrix I have gotten is symmetric, but usually positive definite (the eigenvalues tends to be non-zero, say, 0.004).

- Is there a way to update the positive definite matrix into a positive
  semidefinite matrix?

  If not, is there a better method for generating large, positive
  semidefinite matrix?

Comment: You could randomly generate an $m \times n$ matrix $M$, with $m < n$ (so the null space of $M$ is nontrivial), then set $A = M^T M$. Then $A$ is symmetric PSD and has some zero eigenvalues.